# How to add space disk to VM Ubuntu 16.04 on Xen server

Tags: virtualization, disk, storage, xen

I have an Ubuntu 16.04 VM on Xenserver. I add a disk extension to it to increase its storage capacity. I added a disk on Xen, but the problem is that the Ubuntu VM does not detect the added disk volume.

```
/dev/mapper/apache--vg-root   48G   42G  3.2G  94% /
```

[image: output of df -h]

Answer (score 0):

Inside the Ubuntu VM:

1. Install `gparted` (opening the Terminal and typing `sudo apt-get install gparted`)
2. Open `gparted` (either via the Applications menu or `sudo gparted` from the Terminal)
3. If you see a swap partition, take note of its size. Then right-click on it and select `swapoff`
4. Delete the swap partition
5. Extend the "main" partition with the remaining space, but leaving a space almost the size of the swap partition you just deleted
6. Create a swap partition of the remaining size, with `linux-swap` as file system
7. Click on the green tick to apply changes
8. Right click on the new swap partition and click `swapon`

Source: [StackExchange answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/407090)